# Understanding getline()'s behaviour with scanf on empty line at beginning of stream

Tags: c++, input, scanf, getline

I am reading the following from STDIN

```
2

hello world

bye world
```

using the following code:

```
scanf("%d", &n);
while(getline(cin, str))
    cout << "*" << str << endl;
```

This is the output:

```
*
*
*hello world
*
*bye world
```

When I modify the code to read in the first line entirely using `scanf("%d\n", &n)`, `getline` ignores the first empty line:

```
*hello world
*
*bye world
```

My question is why is `getline` ignoring the first empty line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is why is `getline` ignoring the first empty line?

It isn't; `scanf` is skipping over it. Any amount of consecutive whitespace (such as `\n`) in the format string causes it to skip any amount of consecutive whitespace (such as two linebreaks) in the input.